# Set environment var to docker container created in python

Tags: python, docker, environment-variables

I'm developing an application that creates a container and runs it, using a docker image.

I create the client using this snippet:

 `client = docker.DockerClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock', version='1.41', timeout=10)`

and it's fine.
I instantiate and run the image properly using this: 
 `client.containers.run(image=deployment_json['container_image'], command="sbt run", environment=cfg)`
The environment parameter does not lead into error, and the container runs fine, but the image doesn't retrieve the environment variable (NullPointer, it's a Scala app)
the cfg is created like this: `cfg = ['var_name', str(env)]` where env is a json object.

Using docker lib version 5.0.0.
What am I missing? How do i give environment variables to docker images?

Comment: What does `env` contain?

Comment: it's a json... in the scala app, i retrieve this json as a string and then treat it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) cli perspective you have `--env , -e` flag to set environment variables when running `docker run`

From docs I think this can be achieved using `environment` var:

```py
exec_run(cmd, stdout=True, stderr=True, stdin=False, tty=False, privileged=False, user='', detach=False, stream=False, socket=False, environment=None, workdir=None, demux=False)
```

where you should pass as an argument the `environment` variable

`environment (dict or list)` – Environment variables to set inside the container, as a dictionary or a list of strings in the format `["SOMEVARIABLE=xxx"]`.

Comment: exactly what i did, if you would read. but thank you for the effort

Comment: maybe i created the dict the wrong way, wait

Comment: Yes sorry I've missed it, I think `cfg = ['var_name', str(env)]` does not look ok it should be more like this `["SOMEVARIABLE=xxx"]`

Comment: exactly. my fault of course.. I'll mark your answer as useful, but not as solution if you'd like

Comment: Sure man, I just wanted to help I'm not a reputation hunter .

Comment: or, edit the comment and mark the fact i was creating the dict the wrong way. you deserve it